# Symfony3 - Undefined Index(decode JSON->Object->Array)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, symfony

I create Project Manager Software online, but I have error:
[picture with data and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXDyG.png)

From JavaScript I send data(you can see on the picture), next I get it and decode JSON in result I have stdClass(I try get data for example $data->{"calendarId"}, but I get error: Undefined property: stdClass). Object is converted to array, but again is error. 
Fragment code:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $data=json_decode($request->getContent());
        $data=get_object_vars($data);
        echo var_dump($data);
        echo print_r($data);
        //echo $data->{'startTime'} == ERROR Undefined property stdClass
        echo $data["startTime"];
}
```

I watched many soulation but problem still keep

Comment: It would be better for us to help you if you could copy the error message and the print_r data here instead of in a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems very clear: You should use `startTask` not `startTime`

```
echo $data["startTask"];
```